# Fine Uploader - Using server-side generated thumbnails for the "Initial File List"

Tags: fine-uploader

I saw a couple of messages about this topic, but I still haven't found how to make Fine Uploader use thumbnails *generated by the server* for the [Initial File List](https://docs.fineuploader.com/features/session.html) files.

I use a "traditional" server-side Fine Uploader implementation, for pictures upload,  as described in the [Getting Started](https://docs.fineuploader.com/quickstart/01-getting-started.html) section. But I also want to use Fine Uploader as a gallery to show already uploaded pictures, so I use the "`session`" config to populate it, when it loads...

This works, but Fine Uploader creates Base64 images for those already uploaded images, even if I return a `thumbnailUrl` property for each of them, pointing to already resized thumbnails... Indeed, when I upload pictures, I generate thumbnails on the server, by myself. I want Fine Uploader to display *those thumbnails* when the "Initial File List" is received. How can I achieve this?

I've read about the [drawThumbnail()](https://docs.fineuploader.com/api/methods.html#drawThumbnail) function, but I don't know exactly how to use it. Should I call it manually in the `onSessionRequestComplete` event? Will that prevent Fine Uploader to create Base64 thumbnails by itself?